# Spawn another vim terminal split by shell command while in terminal mode?

Tags: shell, vim, terminal

I like the new command `:terminal`, now I try to use it for my usual terminal tasks. 
When I run `$xterm &` in that Vim terminal mode 'split' it opens a new terminal window with WM. Can I have some shell command to run another terminal inside parent Vim?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you want a shell command that opens vim in terminal mode?

You can simply use -c while invoking vim to supply a command. For instance you could put

```
[[ $VIMTERM ]] || VIMTERM=true vim +terminal +start
```

in your .bashrc to open vim in terminal mode when opening a new shell.

If you want to create a new terminal window within vim you could first exit TERMINAL mode with `CTRL-\ CTRL-n` and then use `:split +term` or `:vs +term`

> Edit after comments below

If you want to send keys to vim from the command line you need to use its `--servername` functionality. For instance, start your first instance with

```
vim --servername vimserv
```

Then once inside vim's terminal you can use

```
vim --servername vimserv --remote-send "<C-w>:term<CR>"
```

Comment: Say I use vifm and mpv much. And I have keybindings with them to run a new terminal window with some other util. I want that new window to spawn inside vim.

Comment: By putting the above in your `.bashrc` any `--login` shell should reference it and spawn vim.

Comment: I don't need a vim terminal on shell login. By a shell command in vim terminal I want to spawn new terminals which will be placed inside vim. If I could simulate `<c-\><c-n>` hit or  `:vs +term` call.

Comment: @PossumGallo Ah, I see what you want now, see my edits

Comment: I can't help but feel like simply typing `<C-\><C-N><C-W>v` would be faster/easier.

Comment: heh, say I have a music folder under cursor in `vifm` and I want it to be played in text mode `mpv` by a single hotkey strike, in a new split ofcourse.

Comment: @PossumGallo not sure what you're asking. is the video an example of what you want to happen or what is happening?

Comment: @PossumGallo instead of using vifm inside a term inside of vim you might just use a vim file manager such as netrw, NERDTree, FuzzyFinder, Ctrl-p, etc